# How to send the authentication related messages in linux to a particular process using rsyslog.conf

Tags: linux, python, syslog, rsyslog

In my system i am having rsyslog daemon running. I tried to configure syslog.conf to sent all authentication mail to a particular file using the line

```
auth.*;authpriv.*        /var/log/AuthLogs
```

its working. Now i want to send these messages to a process. The process will be ready to capture the logs. previously i was using syslogd daemon. In that i was able to send the log using the line below

```
auth.*;authpriv.*        |exec /usr/bin/read.exe
```

But the same is not working with rsyslogd. Do any one have any clue how to do this?

**UPDATE**: Particularly this issue happens with python scripts
ex code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import sys
import fcntl, os   

message = sys.stdin.readline() # Read what's waiting, in one go
if not message:
    print "nothing in message\n"
fd = open('/tmp/testrsyslogomoutput1.txt', 'a')
fd.write("Receiving log message : \n%s\n" % (message))
fd.close()
```

This python code i want to invoke through rsyslog.

Answer (score 1):

I'Am checked Google and found this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87223/rsyslog-execute-script-on-matching-log-event). I've checked example and found that in your case, you should change you string to:

```
auth.*;authpriv.*        ^/usr/bin/read.exe
```

**Update:** I created simple script that contained only `echo $1 >> /var/log/tt.log`. After this I see in log file all messages passed to this script.

Comment: This will defnitely execute the command. But i need to pass the message also to the command.

Comment: @joseph it actually pass message to the command. See updated answer.

Comment: thanks for your support. For bash scripts its running. But i want it to run for python scripts. its not running for python scripts

Answer (score 1):

Depends whether you want to invoke an external program for each instance of a matching message (in which case the `^command' functionality should work for you getting the log message as a parameter).

If you want to pass all matching messages to the standard input of a long running program then I think you want rsyslog's `omprog' functionality. See http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omprog.html for full details. Example config (from that page) ...

```
module(load="omprog")
action(type="omprog"
       binary="/pathto/omprog.py --parm1=\"value 1\" --parm2=\"value2\""
       template="RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat")
```

Comment: I tried this but its not working. I think omprog libraries are not there in my system.